# Insert and Update Data from Check Combo-box to SQL server using c#

Tags: c#, sql, checkbox, combobox

[Combobox-Checkbox SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MftBE.jpg)

I am new to C#. I Installed a library from NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/Common.CheckComboBox/ (Multiple Checkbox with Combo-box). If the checkbox is selected insert 1 in SQL Server or else 0 is inserted in SQL Server. In Normal Checkbox, I know how to insert the data but its multiple checkboxes in combo-box help me solve the problem.

Code:

```
 string[] color = new string[6] { "Blue", "Red", "Orange", "Pink", "White","Grey" };
 for (int i = 0; i < color.Length; i++)
    {
       checkedComboBox1.Items.Add(color[i]);
    }
 checkedComboBox1.SetItemChecked(1, true);
```

Comment: What are you using the access the SQL database? Are you using the .NET Framework SqlClient, EntityFramework or something else? What have you tried so far. This is a bit vague.

Comment: .NET Framework SqlClient,

Answer (score 1):

Using the SqlClient classes built into the .NET Framework:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
{
     conn.Open();
     for (int i = 0; i < checkedComboBox1.Items.Count; i++)
     {
         using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
         {
             cmd.Connection = conn;
             bool isChecked = checkedComboBox1.GetItemChecked(i);
             string colour = checkedComboBox1.Items[i].ToString();
             cmd.CommandText = $"UPDATE TableName SET [{colour}] = '{(isChecked ? 1 : 0)}'";
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }
     }
     conn.Close();
}
```

For the INSERT for all colours at once, as the drop down list is hard-coded string array you can do something like this, but it is not very good practice to hard-code things.

```
string blueChecked = checkedComboBox1.GetItemChecked(0) ? "1" : "0";
string redChecked = checkedComboBox1.GetItemChecked(1) ? "1" : "0";
string orangeChecked = checkedComboBox1.GetItemChecked(2) ? "1" : "0";
string pinkChecked = checkedComboBox1.GetItemChecked(3) ? "1" : "0";
string whiteChecked = checkedComboBox1.GetItemChecked(4) ? "1" : "0";
string greyChecked = checkedComboBox1.GetItemChecked(5) ? "1" : "0";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
{
     conn.Open();
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
     {
          cmd.Connection = conn;
          cmd.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO Colors VALUES ({blueChecked}, {redChecked}, {orangeChecked}, " +
          $"{pinkChecked}, {whiteChecked}, {greyChecked})";
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
     conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Response I updated my image. I think you understand that image  my question is

Comment: Please see updated answer and let me know how you get on :)

Comment: What's the error? You can change the CommandText from "UPDATE" to "INSERT INTO" to insert a row, but this will keep inserting new rows and not update any existing ones.

Comment: cmd.CommandText = $"insert into Colors [{colour}] = '{(isChecked ? 1 : 0)}'"; got syntax error

Comment: Apologies, the insert should be INSERT INTO Colors (Columns, To, Insert, Into) VALUES (Value, Value, Value, Value)